# Is it true that port replicators will stop WiFi from working and why?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb-c, docking-station

I was interested in buying [Vention USB-C type Adapter](https://www.ventioncable.com/usb-type-c-adapter/) (port replicator). But right know, I was shocked, reading the [FAQ on their website](https://www.ventioncable.com/8-typical-questions-of-usb-type-c-converter/):

> 4. Will WIFI usage be affected? Will the wifi break when usb type-c converter connected?
>
> Yes, wifi stops working.

What?

1. Is it true that port replicators break WiFi?
2. Why?
3. Are all port replicators doing that?

That piece of hardware is quite expensive, and it breaks WiFi? ... I am quite shocked that they write it just like that without explanation.

Comment: Probably EM interference.

Comment: Could be, but, if port replicators would break WiFi, how useless is that?? Doesn't make any sense to invest 70 USD in something that breaks my WiFi!

Answer (score 2):

A normal USB-C Port replicator should not make WIFI stop.

The only reason why I can think of this happening, is that if the dongle has a LAN port and you connect the cable, the OS will switch to LAN so you don't have to automatically disable WIFI yourself.

If this is the case with this device, I don't know. It can also be that this is a problem with this specific device and due to a lot of complaints, they just added it in the FAQ rather than solving the issue.

Daniel B mentions EM interference could be the cause. If the USB C replicator uses really cheap parts and is not properly shielded, a little bit of EM interference may cause the wifi signal to become weaker. It will not stop wifi, but it could cause disconnects. Again, only with this device not all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: This really is about USB 3.0 stopping 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi. There's plenty of information about it on the net. But yes, proper EM design could reduce the problem.

Comment: @DanielB interesting. We sell plenty of port replicators, even USB 3.0 ones, haven't seen wifi problems with them.